# Kotlin domain class casting to subclass

Tags: inheritance, kotlin

I have a domain class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
open class User(
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    open var id: Long = 0L,

    @Column(nullable = false)
    var name: String? = null)
```

And I have a subclass of this domain class that I would like to add a JsonIgnore annotation:

```
open class UserFiltered(
    @Id
    @JsonIgnore
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    override var id: Long = 0L
): User()
```

But when I try to cast the User to UserFiltered:

```
return ResponseModel<UserFiltered>(true, userModified as UserFiltered)
```

I get the following error:

> java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   com.example.platform.database.domain.User cannot be cast to
>   com.example.platform.model.UserFiltered   at
>   com.example.platform.controller.UserController.modifyUser(UserController.kt:71)
>   ~[classes/:na]

Is there a way to achieve this in Kotlin, or I will have to do the full cast, setting up every parameter on User?

Comment: are you sure `userModified` is an instance of UserFiltered? could you please edit your question with the code of the creation of `userModified`

Comment: `userModified` is an instance of `User`, but when I want to cast it to `UserFiltered`, I got the error. I thought Kotlin were doing this authomatically, but I found the solution. I'll post it in a minutes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to modify the child class to the following form:

```
open class UserFiltered(
    @Id
    @JsonIgnore
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    override var id: Long = 0L
): User(){
    constructor(user: User): this(user.id)
}
```

And creating the instance of UserFiltered

```
return ResponseModel<UserFiltered>(true, UserFiltered(userModified))
```

Comment: So essentially, you created a "copy constructor" that takes in the base user class and creates a `UserFiltered` instance. Your old code did not work, because the `userModified` is only an instance of the base class, but not the `UserFiltered` class, so it could not be cast to it, as the compiler has no way of validating, that they will always share the same members.